# cant find style.xml in android studio

Tags: java, android, xml, android-studio

So we all know that i gotta go res->values->style.xml right? i do that and I cant find the style.xml file... all I could find is the color.xml and the strings.xml ... obviously there is also the themes folder but if I get to open it, it still doesn't contain style.xml... here is a screen shot of my project.[here is the project with the (android) view and with both the res and themes folder dropped down(clickme)](https://i.stack.imgur.com/97R8B.png)

if you could help that would be really good cuz I'm tryna get my actionbar removed and all I see is that I have to find the styles.xml file to get to remove the action bar...

*also the project is a java project in android studio and it is an *Empty activity*... ty

Comment: styles.xml has been replaced with themes.xml. Use it instead of styles. Or just create a new xml file named *styles*

Comment: Oh thanks ali.. but do you know why did they do that? just so I could get some clearification

Answer (score 1, accepted):

A style is a collection of attributes that specify the appearance for a single View. A style can specify attributes such as font color, font size, background color, and much more.

A theme is a collection of attributes that's applied to an entire app, activity, or view hierarchy—not just an individual view. When you apply a theme, every view in the app or activity applies each of the theme's attributes that it supports. Themes can also apply styles to non-view elements, such as the status bar and window background.
[documentation](https://developer.android.com/guide/topics/ui/look-and-feel/themes#:%7E:text=A%20style%20is%20a%20collection,not%20just%20an%20individual%20view.)

You can create style.xml file manually if you need it.

Comment: So how can i make the action bar disabled with the themes.xml? but thanks for the clearification

Comment: As in style file <style name="Theme.MyApplication" parent="Theme.MaterialComponents.DayNight.NoActionBar"> and <style name="Theme.MyApplication" parent="Theme.MaterialComponents.DayNight.NoActionBar">

Comment: you mean i gotta make a style.xml file and type these code things?

Comment: Oh nevermind thanks for the tip man.... really helpful.... i literally started learning this android studio programing thing a few days ago and its amazing that I got the clarification on what I do in such cases... thanks god bless you

Comment: @OsamaFaris a meant that themes.xml have same attributes as style.xml and you can use the same approach;)

Comment: Thank you sooo much god bless you :)